# c# Regexp replace \n

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to remove any new line characters after `[/quote]`

I have this currently:

`Comment = Regex.Replace(Comment, @"[/quote](\n){1,}", "[/quote]");`

But it doesn't seem to do anything!

Example:

```
[/quote]


hey nice quote blah blah
```

Goes to

```
[/quote]hey nice quote blah blah
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your string ends with `\n` (UNIX-style line ending), and not `\r\n` (Windows-style line ending)?

Also, realize that `[...]` in a regex indicates a character class, so your `[/quote]` matches a single character that is either `/`, `q`, `u`, `o`, `t`, or `e`. You have to escape the `[` as `\[` to match an open-bracket character.

Put them together (and simplify `{1,}` to the shorthand `+`), and try this:

```
Regex.Replace(Comment, @"\[/quote\][\r\n]+", "[/quote]");
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you!  Does the `[\r\n]` match either of them then?

Comment: @Tom: It matches at least one of them, so all of these are matched: `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`, `\n\r`, `\r\r\r\r`, `\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n`, `\r\r\n\r\n\n\n\r` etc

Answer (score 0):

add a "+" after "\n" to match all the \n's

Answer (score 0):

you also need to escape the newline
[/quote][\\n]+

Answer (score 0):

try to use this regex

```
string strRegex = @"\[/quote\][\n\r]+";   
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);

string strReplace = "[/quote]";
return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```